# Android: how do I create a listview screen with different content for each row

Tags: android, listview, varying

I'm looking to create a listview screen similar to the Sound Setting screen (in the built in Settings app, see image below), i.e I want some rows to have text + checkboxes, other rows to have text + "pop up" buttons, some rows should have text only etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a listview, that's a `PreferenceActivity`. Take a look at the PrefereceActivity class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html

If you really want to have a different view for each row in a listview (which is very valid), you'll have to create your own class that extends `BaseAdapter`. In the `getView()` method, just return the view you want to show. There are plenty of examples online.

Comment: Just goes to show how little I know about Android. PreferenceActivity will suit me fine.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Falmarri, that isn't a `ListView` but a `PreferenceActivity`.

If you can't work with the `PreferenceActivity`, the simplest way to make a list of different items that will scroll if they out-grow the screen, is to place a `ScrollView` around a `LinearLayout`. You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Below is a very simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="Some text label here" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
            <Button
                android:text="A button to click"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Perhaps an input field here"
        />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:text="Some more text, and a check box" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now this list doesn't contain enough items to scroll, but if you keep adding more elements to it it will start to scroll as soon as it gets bigger than the screen.